# Why \eqref is not working in sections of beamer?

Tags: beamer

Why this is not work in beamer?

```
\documentclass[hyperref]{beamer}
\usepackage{hyperref}
...
\subsubsection{\protect Verification of \eqref{item:c}}
...
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). A side note: there is no need to load `hyperref`; it's automatically loaded by the Beamer class. The class option `[hyperref]` is used to set options for the `hyperref` package.

Comment: Any way, I have solved by: `\subsubsection{Verification of \protect\eqref{item:c}}`